# How to combine multi csv files into one csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using below code, but it is not useful

```py
def create_final(**kwargs):
    file_list = [imp_path + f for f in os.listdir(imp_path) if f.startswith('Sales_Month')]
    csv_list = []
    for file in sorted(file_list):
        csv_list.append(pd.read_csv(file), encoding='UTF-8',keep_default_na=False))
    csv_merged = pd.concat(csv_list, ignore_index=True)
    csv_merged.to_csv(imp_path + 'sales_records_full.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: define: "not useful"

Comment: I mean, it is not working as expected

Comment: So what's actually happening? Are only some of the files included? Did you actually call the function? Where is `imp_path` defined? No else here as access to your system, so "this doesn't work" 1) isn't a question and 2) isn't something we can practically solve

Comment: imp_path = r'C:/Users/sati/Documents/sales/'

Comment: it s defined as mentioned above

Comment: yes i call the function, ValueError:No object to concatenate

Comment: you should edit the question to include all of the relevant information